# Request.ServerVariables in function

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public static string Call()
{
    string ref1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
    Response.write(ref1);
}

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Call()
}
```

> CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Response.get'

Answer (score 10):

`Response` is an instance property on the `Page` class, provided as a shortcut to `HttpContext.Current.Response`.

Either use an instance method, or use `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write` in your static method.

**Examples**

```
public static string Call()
{
    string ref1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ref1);
}
```

Or

```
public string Call()
{
    string ref1 = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
    Response.Write(ref1);
}
```

The mention of a `get()` method in `System.Web.UI.Page.Response.get` refers to the property's get accessor. Essentially, it is saying that you can't call the get() method on an instance of a type from a static method of a type (which of course makes sense).

As a side note, `Response.write(ref1);` should be `Response.Write()` (corrected case).